# Hibernate performs insert instead of update

Tags: hibernate, insert

I am using hibernate for a kind of music management thing.
The song entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Song")
public class Song implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id")
    private Artist artist;
}
```

The artist entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Artist")
public class Artist implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is that if I post a Song with artist "abc" and after that another Song with artist "abc" another entry in the artist database will be created.

Is there a way to make hibernate look for those "duplicates" or do I have to do this myself?

Comment: if the entity doesn't have the id set it will insert a new record.

Comment: So this means that I have to query for the artist name in advance and fetch the id and attach it to the artist?

Comment: To update that record yes. You should search for the entity which will come back with its id, make the change, and update it.